# Kalman Filter Vs Recursive Least Squares

Tags: normal-distribution, least-squares, kalman-filter

Does the Kalman Filter boil down to Recursive (i.e., incremental) Least Squares if the state is constant?

I expect it does but I am not sure.

Assume that all simplifying assumptions hold (i.e, models are linear, pdfs are all Gaussian etc).

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Recursive Least Squares deals with Measurement Noise.

If you set the Process Noise to zero energy noise then both are equivalent.